# Showing refreshing message in Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using an Action Bar (a regular one, not sherlock) in my android app, and when the app opens I want to show a refreshing message in the action bar. This means I want to hide the menu items and title (similar to how the GMail app appears when it's refreshing).

What is the best approach for this? Is it using a contextual action bar?

Is it possible to show the refreshing animation just below the action bar, like in the GMail app (ie, the blue lines sliding over).

I know I can use a 3rd party pull-to-refresh, but I'd prefer not to use this (as I don't need the pull-to-refresh capability).

I'm targeting Jelly Bean and newer devices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to hide the menu items and title (similar to how the GMail app
>   appears when it's refreshing).

This can be done by using `WindowManager.addView(View, LayoutParams)`. Here's an example of displaying a message on top of the `ActionBar` that should give you a pretty solid idea about how to proceed.

**The layout**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

**Implementation**

```
/** The attribute depicting the size of the {@link ActionBar} */
private static final int[] ACTION_BAR_SIZE = new int[] {
        android.R.attr.actionBarSize
};

/** The notification layout */
private TextView mMessage;

private void showLoadingMessage() {
    // Remove any previous notifications
    removeLoadingMessage();

    // Initialize the layout
    if (mMessage == null) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        mMessage = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
        mMessage.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark));
        mMessage.setText("Loading...");
    }

    // Add the View to the Window
    getWindowManager().addView(mMessage, getActionBarLayoutParams());
}

private void removeLoadingMessage() {
    if (mMessage != null && mMessage.getWindowToken() != null) {
        getWindowManager().removeViewImmediate(mMessage);
        mMessage = null;
    }
}

/**
 * To use, @see {@link WindowManager#addView(View, LayoutParams)}
 * 
 * @return The {@link WindowManager.LayoutParams} to assign to a
 *         {@link View} that can be placed on top of the {@link ActionBar}
 */
private WindowManager.LayoutParams getActionBarLayoutParams() {
    // Retrieve the height of the status bar
    final Rect rect = new Rect();
    getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
    final int statusBarHeight = rect.top;

    // Retrieve the height of the ActionBar
    final TypedArray actionBarSize = obtainStyledAttributes(ACTION_BAR_SIZE);
    final int actionBarHeight = actionBarSize.getDimensionPixelSize(0, 0);
    actionBarSize.recycle();

    // Create the LayoutParams for the View
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, actionBarHeight,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = statusBarHeight;
    return params;
}
```

**Results**

[image: Example]

**Conclusion**

This implementation is very similar to Gmail and other apps, minus the pull-to-refresh pattern.

When you call `showLoadingMessage`, post a `Runnable` or use a `View.OnClickListener`. You don't want to call `WindowManager.addView` too early or you'll throw a `WindowManager.BadTokenException`. Also, it's important to call `removeLoadingMessage` in `Activity.onDestroy`, otherwise you run the risk of leaking the `View` you add to the `Window`.

Comment: Thanks. What's the purpose of posting as a Runnable?

Comment: @WiseShepherd You don't want to call `WindowManager.addView` too early or you'll throw a `WindowManager.BadTokenException`.

Comment: @adneal ,can I animate this view that create from WindowManager.addview? where should I implement the animation?

Comment: @JongzPuangput Yes and after you call `WindowManager.addView`.

Comment: @adneal Thank you for you answer. now I'm trying to set animation but I don't have any experience in animation in android.However, I'm trying but if you can provide some example it would be great!